# SEO pagination link title

Tags: html, seo

I have pagination links like so:

```
<a href="?page=2" rel="next">2</a>
```

Now when searching google google link to this page is `2`, as you see [here (google link)](https://www.google.ee/search?q=ehitusfirmad%20site%3akataloog.ee&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Does adding a title to link(eg. `title="Pagination - Page 2"`) help, so google results are not numberic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choose this format generally so that I have the page in it and the title attribute helps a little for SEO as it states the title:

```
<a href="..." title="My category title - page X">X</a>
```

Comment: So in google search results it shows "My category title - page X", instead of "X"?

Answer (score 2):

Google gets its info from the page itself, not from the link to it. So make sure the page has a proper title element in the head, which contains the title you want.

There seems to be a title element on the page, but that's because they now return a 404-page.

Comment: It has proper title tag.

Comment: This is a half-truth. While much of the info on the page is used for information about itself, information contained in internal and external link texts do matter.

Comment: For ranking, yes, but not for the page title.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set the title element of those pages to "Page x" (instead of leaving only numbers). Additionally, some meta information would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter at all to having page numbers on the title, and also it would be good for users somehow.